# Is Kelvin structure the optimal solution for a three-dimensional foam when restricted to only one shape?

Tags: geometry, optimization, 3d, polyhedra, tiling

[Weaire–Phelan structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weaire%E2%80%93Phelan_structure#History_and_the_Kelvin_problem) is known as a more optimal solution for Kelvin problem than Kelvin structure, which is [Bitruncated cubic honeycomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitruncated_cubic_honeycomb). However, it uses two different shapes. When restricted to only one shape is Kelvin structure the optimal solution for the Kelvin problem?